# Ionic + input range + Internet Explorer = Frozen slider

Tags: ionic-framework, internet-explorer-11, html-input

A [Codepen](http://%20http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPdJRq) to sum-up the problem :

On Google Chrome the slider works. On Internet Explorer it's frozen.

Any idea what the problem is and what could solve this ?

Comment: Same here, changing the value via keyboard is possible though. Also my "thumb" / bullet is missing visually.

Comment: See my workaround here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/range-slider-not-movable-in-internet-explorer/19592